# SQL Insert into table only if record doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to run a set of queries to insert some data into an SQL table but only if the record satisfying certain criteria are met. The table has 4 fields: `id` (primary), `fund_id`, `date` and `price`

I have 3 fields in the query: `fund_id`, `date` and `price`.

So my query would go something like this:

```
INSERT INTO funds (fund_id, date, price)
    VALUES (23, '2013-02-12', 22.43)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * 
       FROM funds 
       WHERE fund_id = 23
         AND date = '2013-02-12'
    );
```

So I only want to insert the data if a record matching the `fund_id` and `date` does not already exist. If the above is correct it strikes me as quite an inefficient way of achieving this as an additional select statement must be run each time.

Is there a better way of achieving the above?

Edit: For clarification neither `fund_id` nor `date` are unique fields; records sharing the same fund_id or date will exist but no record should have both the same fund_id and date as another.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQ, Oracle, MSAccess?

Comment: MySQL although I would like it to work potentially with MSAccess too if poss

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: seems ID and date are your logically unique keys. Why don't you declare them unique and handle database exception on unique key constraint violation?

Comment: The approach is fine.  However, your sql is not valid as pointed out in Trinimon's answer.  You can't have a where clause if you are using the values keyword.

Comment: @BilalMirza ID and date are only unique when combined. I.e. other records can share the date or ID but not both. If this is what you are saying then could you elaborate on how I would do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Although the answer I originally marked as chosen is correct and achieves what I asked there is a better way of doing this (which others acknowledged but didn't go into). A composite unique index should be created on the table consisting of `fund_id` and `date`.

```
ALTER TABLE funds ADD UNIQUE KEY `fund_date` (`fund_id`, `date`);
```

Then when inserting a record add the condition when a conflict is encountered:

```
INSERT INTO funds (`fund_id`, `date`, `price`)
    VALUES (23, DATE('2013-02-12'), 22.5)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price` = `price`; --this keeps the price what it was (no change to the table) or:

INSERT INTO funds (`fund_id`, `date`, `price`)
    VALUES (23, DATE('2013-02-12'), 22.5)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price` = 22.5; --this updates the price to the new value
```

This will provide much better performance to a sub-query and the structure of the table is superior. It comes with the caveat that you can't have NULL values in your unique key columns as they are still treated as values by MySQL.

Comment: Your solution works well, is much tidier and looks more elegant. Is there a performance difference, though? Doesn't the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` perform a subquery anyway?

Comment: The performance of UNIQUE depends on the storage engine. In TokuDB, it is discouraged...

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 60):

This might be a simple solution to achieve this:

```
INSERT INTO funds (ID, date, price)
SELECT 23, DATE('2013-02-12'), 22.5
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM funds 
                    WHERE ID = 23
                      AND date = DATE('2013-02-12'));
```

**p.s.** alternatively (if `ID` a primary key):

```
 INSERT INTO funds (ID, date, price)
    VALUES (23, DATE('2013-02-12'), 22.5)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = 23; -- or whatever you need
```

see [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03384/1).

Comment: How is this different/better than my original method?

Comment: This is not different. But it's valid SQL. @harryg have you tried your statement?

Comment: Ok, this one should work now (`FROM dual`  was missing). Adjusted my example to fit your code above

Comment: @ypercube No I haven't tried my statement as it is still conceptual at this point. So what is the purpose of `dual`? I have googled around but it's not clear how this statement works...

Comment: It's exactly what you were trying to do. But MySQL syntax does not allow `WHERE` on an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement. You have to rewrite with `INSERT ... SELECT`. The `dual` is a special table with just one row (and one its uses is like this, to create a table with one row so it can be inserted into `funds`.)

Comment: Yes, `FROM dual` means you select these values as a query result (_from nowhere_ so to say); and selecting values gives you the possibility to add a `WHERE` condition - something that `VALUES` doesn't offer. Alternatively you could use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, but this requires ID to be a primary key; see updated Fiddle

Comment: OK great. I tried your method and it seems to work. Tried it on about 5000 rows and it took around 20s to execute so not the most efficient but adequate for my needs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: that's a lot of variables to keep track of / maintain.  @harryg, did you try answer?

Comment: @gillyspy not sure what you mean... I tried the answer above and it worked. I was originally looking for a solution that does the same as above but much more efficiently.

Comment: @harryg, gillyspy: if you have an index on ID, both statements are probably the fastest possibilities. May be you can gain some extra performance by executing multiple statements in one transaction (i.e. avoid commits after every statement): check for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896162/mysql-innodb-insert-performance-windows; also locking tables seems interesting, check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html

Comment: With sqlite, it might be possible to bypass the need for a "dual" table. Rapid tests give appear to give the expected results with "INSERT INTO funds SELECT 23 as ID, DATE('2013-02-12') as date, 22.5 as price WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM funds WHERE ID = 23 AND date = DATE('2013-02-12'))"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you cannot modify DDL (to create a unique constraint) or are limited  to only being able to write DML then check for a null on filtered result of your values against the whole table

### [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cbd9/11)

```
insert into funds (ID, date, price) 
select 
    T.* 
from 
    (select 23 ID,  '2013-02-12' date,  22.43 price) T  
        left join 
    funds on funds.ID = T.ID and funds.date = T.date
where 
    funds.ID is null
```