# MySQL: Do not insert a new row if defined rows are same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which I get sampling values: AeroSamples

```
id    time    temperature    pressure    humidity
```

I sample the values at a 5 minute period. Before inserting a new row into the table, I check if the last row's temperature, pressure and humidity values are same with current values. If so, I do not want to add a new row. Else A new record could be added.

I do this like that:

```
SELECT temperature, pressure, humidity FROM AeroSamples ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

When I get the last values, I compare three fields with current values which is the way I do not like:

```
if($row["temperature"] !== $curTemp || $row["pressure"] !== $curPres || $row["humidity"] !== $curHumi)
{
    $db->prepare("INSERT INTO AeroSamples (temperature, pressure, humidity) VALUES(:t,:p,:h)");
    ...
}
```

How can I do this SQL only?

Does `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` help me? I do not think so. Because I am not sure if it is valid for multiple fields at a time.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE` will help, yes. Have you tried using it?

Comment: maybe this link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460397/sql-insert-into-table-only-if-record-doesnt-exist

Comment: @DigitalChris If at least one field is different it should be recorded. If the 3 fields' all are same will not be recorded. Changing ORs to ANDs will not help me if only one field is different.

Comment: Also, this question gives me the willies. Unchanged data is entirely different from missing data. In analyzing the data you want to differentiate between 2 hours of unchanged weather and 2 hours of server downtime.

Comment: @DigitalChris I do not care about server downtime matters. Just want to know if this check could be done using MySQL only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous values will *not* be the same, because the time is different.  Alas.

You can do this using the `insert . . . select` syntax.  The idea is to select the last row inserted and use a `where` clause to filter the rows.  The filter will return no rows (and hence no insert) when the values are the same:

```
insert into AeroSamples(temperature, pressure, humidity) 
    select :t, :p, :h
    from (select temperature, pressure, humidity
          from AeroSamples
          order by id desc
          limit 1
         ) as1
    where as1.temperature <> :t or as1.pressure <> :p or as1.humidity <> :h;
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'd like to do this too but in my case I do a multirow insert with thousands of rows. Would there be any way of making it do this check for each row?

Comment: @clox . . . You should ask another question with details about what you want to happen.  But, yes, I think this can be adapted.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898733/insert-multiple-records-only-if-they-differ-from-the-last-ones

Answer (score 0):

In order to use ON DUPLICATE you will need to add a unique index to your table.

```
create unique index aerosamples_ux1 on AeroSamples(temperature, pressure, humidity);
```

than you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE inside your queries... also keep in mind if you dont use ON DUPLICATE you query will give you an error and won't add a duplicate record after adding this index.

Comment: There should be no duplicating combinations of temparature, pressure and humidity *in two neighbouring rows*, not the entire table.

Comment: Yo are right in this case it may not be useful unless you add another field to database and index. I just wanted to clarify use case of ON DUPLICATE because it was a part in original question.