# SQL Server parameterized query with a WHERE clause with Nulls

Tags: sql-server, null, where-clause, parameterized-query

VB.NET 2012, ADO.NET, SQL Server 2014

I setup a parameterized query that works well. I essentially read records from a `DataTable` that comes from a different source than my SQL Server. It's small enough that I elected to read record by record and build a query and hit the SQL Server for a match.

However I am having trouble getting a match when one of my fields is supposed to be matched for a null. I know a record exist because I can look at it in SQL Server directly and see it. With my parameterized query somehow the null is being translated improperly. I tried manually replacing the parameter `@EngSerialNo` with `DBNull.Value` and still doesn't work. Almost seems like I need two different queries depending if my `DataTable` value is null.

```
sqQry.AppendLine("SELECT CityCode,CarNum,RegNum,Event,EngSerialNum)")
sqQry.AppendLine("FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Events]")
sqQry.AppendLine("WHERE (CityCode=@City AND CarNum=@CarNo AND RegNum=@RegNo AND Event=@Event AND EngSerialNum=@EngSerialNo)") 'this looks for a value in EngSerialNo
'sqQry.AppendLine("WHERE (CityCode=@City AND CarNum=@CarNo AND RegNum=@RegNo AND Event=@Event AND EngSerialNum IS NULL)")     'this looks for a Null in EngSerialNo     

 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

 With cmd
        .Connection = connMyDb
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = sqQry.ToString

         'cycle through each DataRow in the DataTable and check for returns
         Dim total As Integer = 0
         For Each row As DataRow In dtMain.Rows
             .Parameters.Clear()
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", row.Item("City"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarNo", row.Item("CarNo"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", row.Item("RegNo"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event", row.Item("Event"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EngSerialNo", row.Item("EngSerialNo")) 'how do I get this to look for a null value when the DataTable contains a null value?

             Dim rowsAffected As Integer = .ExecuteNonQuery()
             total += rowsAffected
         Next row
End With
```

Update: I ended up creating a dynamic SQL for every DataRow. Basically for each DataRow I check key fields for NULL or an actual value and create the appropriate SQL command text. I have 4 fields that could contain a NULL but for sake of simplicity I only demonstrated one here. I think the developer can follow the example to create their own query.

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
 With cmd
        .Connection = connMyDb
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text

         'cycle through each DataRow in the DataTable and check for returns
         Dim total As Integer = 0
         For Each row As DataRow In dtMain.Rows
             .CommandText = BuildSql(row)

             .Parameters.Clear()
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", row.Item("City"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarNo", row.Item("CarNo"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", row.Item("RegNo"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event", row.Item("Event"))
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EngSerialNo", row.Item("EngSerialNo")) 

             Dim rowsAffected As Integer = .ExecuteNonQuery()
             total += rowsAffected
         Next row
End With

Private Function BuildSql(ByVal dr As DataRow) As String
     Dim sqQry As New StringBuilder
     sqQry.AppendLine("SELECT CityCode,CarNum,RegNum,Event,EngSerialNum)")
     sqQry.AppendLine("FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Events]")

     If dr.Item("EngSerialNo") Is DBNull.Value Then
        sqQry.AppendLine("WHERE (CityCode=@City AND CarNum=@CarNo AND RegNum=@RegNo AND Event=@Event AND EngSerialNum IS NULL)")     'this looks for a Null in EngSerialNo            
     Else
        sqQry.AppendLine("WHERE (CityCode=@City AND CarNum=@CarNo AND RegNum=@RegNo AND Event=@Event AND EngSerialNum=@EngSerialNo)") 'this looks for a value in EngSerialNo
     End If

     Return sqQry.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL you can't compare null values, i.e. `EngSerialNum = null` always evaluates to false, even if the value in the field is null.

Either you can create the query dynamically so that you use `is null` to match the null values, or you can use an expression like this:

```
((EngSerialNum is null and @EngSerialNo is null) or EngSerialNum = @EngSerialNo)
```

Comment: Well I did some research and it was stated that setting ANSI_NULLS on the database itself as an option would do what I need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx Tried it and it didn't work. I'll give your suggestion a go. I actually have two fields that I need to check for so luckily I don't have to write a huge alternative query.

Comment: @sinDizzy: You would use `set ansi_nulls off` to be able to compare null values. However, that possibility will be removed in the future. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean now. So will implement my query that is not dependent on that setting. In other words use an IS NULL. I'll post once I have something that works.

Comment: I ended up creating a dynamic SQL based on the value of each field that can be NULL. Its a bit more work but I don't have that many records to cycle through. Updated my post with pseudo code of the solution.

Comment: Nice work with the expression. That also has the added benefit that it doesn't bloats the query cache with many similar plans.